# Why does memcpy_s zeroize in the case of runtime constraint violation?

Tags: c, memory

In this [implementation of `memcpy_s`](https://github.com/coruus/safeclib/blob/88a3bf7c7e4cd6f0b7a8559050523bacb31362f3/src/safeclib/memcpy_s.c#L74) ([as well as others](https://github.com/microsoft/ChakraCore/blob/39078423036150a32059b315ff4d7e8d2cbced87/pal/src/safecrt/memcpy_s.c#L70)) the region pointed to by `dest` is zeroized when a runtime constraint violation occurs.

Can anyone explain why is this done?  I got footguned by this a few days back and I would be interested in knowing *why* this is done.

Comment: Because this is the only safe thing to do. This is what makes it safer than strncpy and memcpy, etc. The point of the "new" "safe" copy methods is that a partial buffer content is a bad thing, even if properly null terminated.

Comment: Are you asking why the implementation fills the buffer when a) the source pointer is `NULL` or b) when the buffer provided is too small? Perhaps to produce a repeatable result.

Comment: @GemTaylor just be aware that `strncpy` is not at all the somewhat safer version of `strcpy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is documented in section K.3.7.1.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) as well as the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/memcpy-s-wmemcpy-s?view=vs-2019).

The reason for this most likely is to have deterministic behavior in the failure case so that you don't end up with `dest` containing uninitialized values.  This allows for more robust testability.